# Database selection using route prefixing in cakephp 2.4?

Tags: cakephp

I'm working on a system which may be used by different segments. Each will have it's own separate database, but all with the same functionalities. I'd like to have a prefix in my routes so I could select the database.

I found and tried to follow this suggestion: [CakePHP - select database config based on route or url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904260/cakephp-select-database-config-based-on-route-or-url)

So using the above answer, I have this setup:

route.php:

```
App::uses('SystemSelector', 'Routing/Route');

Router::connect('/:sys/*', array(), array('routeClass' => 'SystemSelector'));

Router::connect('/:sys',             array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
Router::connect('/:sys/users/logout', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout'));
Router::connect('/:sys/users/add',    array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'add'));

Router::connect('/:sys/tickets/index', array('controller' => 'tickets', 'action' => 'index'));
Router::connect('/:sys/tickets/view', array('controller' => 'tickets', 'action' => 'view'));
Router::connect('/:sys/tickets/add', array('controller' => 'tickets', 'action' => 'add'));
```

SystemSelector.php:

```
class SystemSelector extends CakeRoute {
    // see http://book.cakephp.org/view/1634/Custom-Route-classes
    public function parse($url) {
        $params = parent::parse($url);
        if (empty($params)) {
           return false;
        }

        switch ($params['sys']) {
            case 'test':
                DbSelector::$ds = 'test';
                break;
            case 'example':
                DbSelector::$ds = 'example';
                break;            
            default:
                throw new Exception('Bad route');
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

and my AppModel.php:

```
class AppModel extends Model {
    public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
        $ds = DbSelector::$ds;
        parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that at my appController.php I have:

```
public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'DebugKit.Toolbar',
        'Auth' => array(
            'authenticate' => array(
                'Form' => array(
                    'passwordHasher' => 'My64',
                    'fields' => array('username' => 'user_login',
                                      'password' => 'user_senha')
                )
            ),
            'loginAction'    => array('controller' => 'users',   'action' => 'login'),
            'loginRedirect'  => array('controller' => 'tickets', 'action' => 'index'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users',   'action' => 'login')
        )
    );
```

and the login redirect takes me to example.com/tickets/index , which I think I should make:
example.com/:sys/tickets/index.

How do I pass the :sys prefix to this loginRedirect option?
Also, how do I create links inside my views with the correct :sys prefix?

Or am I completely off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand you are looking for the `persist` option, it defines which parameters should automatically be included when generating URLs. Also you might want to make use of the `controller` and `action`.

Example:

```
$options = array(
    'routeClass' => 'SystemSelector'
    'persist'    => array('sys')
);

Router::connect(
    '/:sys/',
    array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
    $options
);

Router::connect(
    '/:sys/:controller',
    array('action' => 'index'),
    $options
);

Router::connect(
    '/:sys/:controller/:action/*',
    array(),
    $options
);
```

For all matching routes this should automatically include the appropriate value passed for the `sys` parameter when generating URLs.

See also **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#Router::connect**